# How affects the final result baking diffuse from high poly?

Tags: texture-baking, baking

I have created a pickaxe and have already textured it.

I have textured the low poly mesh and used the high poly mesh just for baking the normal map. Should I texture the high poly and bake on the low poly like I did for the normal map?

If I do this what will be the differences?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read a variant of that question within the last two days, but here it goes anyway... **It depends what you mean by "texturing"**. Image textures? Procedurally generated materials? You can always use the edit link below your question and add some images that help us to understand your problem. The more information you give us, the more we understand your problem, the less we give generalized answers. Please read [this](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2620/could-we-brush-up-the-help-center-please). It's full of useful links and explanations.

Comment: If you've already textured the low-poly, why would you texture the high-poly? It looks like the high-poly is just here to get the normals, isn't it? So once you've baked the normals, use them in the low-poly material and you are good...

Comment: Ok thanks.I was thinking that if i texture only   the high poly and then bake on the low poly i will obtain a better result